# Have a ruby script output what version of ruby is running it

Tags: ruby

How do I have my ruby script output what version of ruby is running it?

Comment: I assume you aren't interested in whether it's MRI/YARV versus JRuby, IronRuby, Rubinius, etc.?

Comment: @Andrew I'm early enough in learning ruby that I don't know what those are.  For now, I'm working with ruby 1.9.2 and ruby 1.8.7.  I assume these are the 'normal' when compared those you mentioned...  Is there a way to find that out as well?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `RUBY_VERSION` constant contains the version number of the ruby interpreter and `RUBY_PATCHLEVEL` contains the patchlevel, so this:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
```

outputs e.g. `2.2.3`, while this:

```
puts RUBY_PATCHLEVEL
```

outputs e.g. `173`. Together it can be used like this:

```
ruby -e 'print "ruby #{ RUBY_VERSION }p#{ RUBY_PATCHLEVEL }"'
```

to output e.g. `ruby 2.2.3p173`

Comment: +1 Excellent.  That's what I needed.  (counting down the minutes until it let's me accept the answer)

Comment: Or, if you just need the major.minor, as I did,`ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION.split(".")[0,2].join(".")'`.

Comment: Or `ruby -e 'require "rbconfig"; puts "#{RbConfig::CONFIG["MAJOR"]}.#{RbConfig::CONFIG["MINOR"]}"'`, but I'm not sure that's better.

Comment: Or `ruby -e 'require "rbconfig"; puts RbConfig::CONFIG["RUBY_API_VERSION"]'`.

Answer (score 5):

For reference, here's how variables and constants work, along with a list of Ruby's built-in variables and constants: [Ruby Programming/Syntax/Variables and Constants](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants) and [Pre-defined Variables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pre-defined_Variables).

You can get a list of all the global constants [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+global+constants), including `RUBY_VERSION` and friends, in the official Ruby language documentation.

For the bonus round, this will tell you some more useful info about your Ruby environment using RbConfig:

```
require 'rbconfig'
puts Config::CONFIG.sort_by{ |n,v| n.downcase }.map{ |n,v| "#{n} => '#{v}'" }
```

Comment: Interesting links, although as you mention, they don't have RUBY_VERSION

Comment: Yeah, I think they need to do a palm-to-forehead slap.

Comment: Another place that documents such globals: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/globals_rdoc.html

Comment: [Fixed now](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#global-constants). It's a wiki. You can edit it!